# What are differences amongst conference, proceedings and inproceedings?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibentry

When I go through the [entry types](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Reference_guide) of `Bibliography` I see three types mean the same thing i.e. `article in a conference paper`. I am really confused which of the types I should use. Could anyone clarify the differences?

[Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex#Reference_guide) defines,

> **conference:**
>
> > An article in a conference proceedings
>
> **inproceedings:**
>
> > An article in a conference proceedings
>
> **proceedings:**
>
> > The same as conference

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the question is tagged as [biblatex](/questions/tagged/biblatex), I answer with some quotes from the `biblatex` documentation (which you can get from [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)).

> #### Regular Types
>
> **proceedings**
>   A single-volume conference proceedings. This type is very similar to `@collection`.
>   It supports an optional `organization` field which holds the sponsoring institution.
>   The `editor` is omissible in terms of § 2.3.2.
>   Required fields: `title`, `year`/`date`
>
> **inproceedings**
>   An article in a conference proceedings. This type is similar to `@incollection`. It
>   supports an optional `organization` field.
>   Required fields: `author`, `title`, `booktitle`, `year`/`date`
>
> #### Type Aliases
>
> **conference**
>   A legacy alias for `@inproceedings`.

To summarize:

- `proceedings` is intended for a collection of articles, typically the written-up contributions of one conference. You use `proceedings` when you want to refer to the collection at large, and not to a single article. A `proceedings` reference thus typically has an `editor` specified rather than an `author`.
- `inproceedings` on the other hand refers to a single article or contribution within a collection, i.e. typically a single written-up conference talk. You use it to refer to this specific contribution, and thus typically specifiy an `author`.
- `conference` is only kept for compatibility reasons, use `inproceedings` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The original LaTeX documentations says the following. Required fields are shown in bold:

> **conference:**
>
> > The same as inproceedings included for compatibility with older versions
>
> **inproceedings:**
>
> > An article in a conference proceedings. Fields: **author, title, booktitle, year**, editor, volume or number, series, pages, address, month, organization, publisher, note
>
> **proceedings:**
>
> > The proceedings of a conference. Fields: **title, year**, editor, volume or number, series, address, month, organization, publisher, note

So conference = inproceedings and the difference between inproceedings and proceedings is in the required fields.

You can also refer to [Tame the BeaST](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf)