# Biblatex apa style editors repeated multiple times

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

When using biblatex with style=apa:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=english]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    
@conference{abc,
 author = {A Author and B Author},
 editor = {A Editor and B Editor},
 year = {2010},
 title = {{Title}},
 booktitle = {Conference title},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Adding a Conference type bib entrance creates output that repeats the editors many times:

[image: Latex Output]

Expected output:

> Author, A. & Author, B. (2010). Title.  In: A.
> Editor & B. Editor (Eds.), *Conference title*. Stuttgart: Springer.

How to make it output the correct format?

Also there should not be a  `,` before the `&` befor last authors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Please add a MWE along with its output and your intended output for better understanding of the issue

Comment: @codeR not sure how to add an intended output differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @InProceedings instead of @conference:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,language=english]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
    
@InProceedings{abc,
 author = {A Author and B Author},
 editor = {A Editor and B Editor},
 year = {2010},
 title = {{Title}},
 booktitle = {Conference title},
 publisher = {Springer},
 address = {Stuttgart}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output
[image]

From the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and this [discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516802/what-are-differences-amongst-conference-proceedings-and-inproceedings):

> conference is only kept for compatibility reasons, use inproceedings instead.

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way to fix the comma before the ampersand?

Comment: I think that is intentional, but of course you can override that. Here are some pointers: [link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/632732/replacing-ampersand-by-and-in-biblatex-and-apa) and [link2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).